# Updating JLabel Icon with something, waiting 2 seconds, then updating with something else?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == push) {
            g.getHuman().beAPig(true);
        }
        else {
            g.getHuman().beAPig(false);
        }

        // take p1 turn and check if players switched
        if (!g.gameOver() && g.playGame()) {
            while(!g.playGame()); // loop until players switched
        }

        updateLabels();

        if (g.gameOver()) {
            gameOverDialog();
        }
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Updates the score labels and die images.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
private void updateLabels() {
    die1Image.setIcon(pair.getDie1Image());
    die2Image.setIcon(pair.getDie2Image());
    p1RoundPointsLabel.setText(Integer.toString(g.getHuman().getRoundPoints()));
    p1GamePointsLabel.setText(Integer.toString(g.getHuman().getGamePoints()));
    p2RoundPointsLabel.setText(Integer.toString(g.getComputer().getRoundPoints()));
    p2GamePointsLabel.setText(Integer.toString(g.getComputer().getGamePoints()));
    sumLabel.setText(pair.toString());
}
```

So the game is called PigDice. A player and computer take turns rolling a pair dice, etc. When a one on either die is rolled, that player's turn is over, and it passes to the other player. The problem is when I roll a one, it instantly switches to the computer, which instantly takes its turn, instantly switching back to me and updating the dice images with the computer's last roll. What I am trying to do is whenever the human rolls something with a 1 in it, it updates the die images so you can see what they rolled, then pauses for 1-2 seconds, THEN updates all the labels with the results of the computer's turn.

I've read a little bit about the EDT (don't have a very complete understanding), and I've tried using Thread.sleep() and InvokeLater() unsuccessfully.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a swing Timer.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, figured it out with that (but in quite a weird manner)